# tutorial to use Chicken of the VNC

Tags: cocoa

How can i use Chicken of the VNC(cotvnc). Please let me know if there is any tutorial for using it.

Comment: wrong tag? do you want to use cotvnc for connecting to a mac?

Comment: @MarmOt: I have that open source code of cotvnc, i just need to use how to use those classes in creating a new project using that.

Comment: This is not programming related. You want superuser.com

Comment: @Joshua: I got the open source project, but it has compilation error on 10.6, cotvnc is an open source library, you can use it for free. check it out on google.

Answer (score 1):

http://murphymac.com/chicken-of-the-vnc/ - A tutorial on how to use Chicken of the VNC on a Mac

Comment: You could also look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_of_the_VNC